# Why my delete button doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, mysql

Some days earlier, I updated my PHP version for my website. I do all the necessary updates but my delete button still doesn't work.

My code of this button :

```
if ($action == "sup") {
    $delete = "DELETE FROM $tb_transac WHERE ($tb_transac.`SID` = '" . $session . "' OR $tb_transac.`SID` = '" . $sess . "') AND no_commande = '" . $no_commande . "'";
    if (!mysqli_query($connect,$delete)) {
        sms_2(sprintf("Error in executing %s stmt", $delete));
        sms_2(sprintf("error:%d %s", mysqli_errno($connect), mysqli_error($connect)));
        exit();
    }
    $step = $_GET['step'];
}
```

Comment: can you please update your whole code?? and if it show any error  put it on your question

Comment: echo your mysql query and run once that in phpmyadmin. Is that working?

Comment: I got no error. I tried to `echo` or `var_dump`, nothing displayed. I will try in phpmyadmin.

Comment: if your mysql query is not getting display then it means your if condition (if ($action == "sup")) is not getting true there.

Comment: what is ` doing at the end of your `if` condition, hope its a typo.

Comment: do `mysqli_query($connect,$delete) or die(mysqli_error())` to see if there is an error in your query

Comment: I tried and nothing displayed, I think my if condition is false like @DeepKakkar said

Comment: I got this in my form button `<input name='action' type='image' value='sup'` so it should works no ?

Comment: Try $_GET['action'] instead of $action. OR $_POST['action'] if post is used. Also please note that if that fixes the problem - you should prorably fix a whole lot of things, as stuff like $action (registered globals) are insecure, as are parameters in your queries.

Comment: I don't know, the website was ever done. I just have to update php on this website

Comment: When you update php, things like "$action" will no longer work if they are being taken from form data. it used to be this way in old php versions, but for security reasons they were deprecated. Now you have to access form fields with $_GET['field_name'] and $_POST['field_name']. If variables like $action and $no_commande come from a web form - you'll have to rewrite them or turn on the register_globals in php.ini (don't know if it will let you do that in new php versions)

Comment: $action is a global variable so you think this error comes from that ?

Comment: If it is supposed to represent your <input> field - then it most likely is your problem. just do var_dump($action) before the "if" statement and you will probably see that this variable is now empty. Just like all the other global variables that come from web forms.

Comment: Yes I got a NULL for $action. So I need to do something like that : `$action = $_POST['action']` ? I don't really see by what you want to replace $action.

Comment: If your form is sending data via post then your example is correct. If it's sending data via get then use $_GET instead of $_POST. Or just try to locate php.ini and enable "register_globals" (i don't recommend doing it though).

Comment: In fact my query is called in a other php page. The query is good but the mysqli_query() answer false so the problem comes from there.